# Working with Webhost and Webhook receivers in a unitTest [.net]

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, http, webhooks

I want to receive a webhook from Postman within a unittest. But i've no clue how to create something like this. I've read the official documentation on webhooks (the receiving end specifically), but i find it rather vague regarding how to set it up.

I've already accomplished to set up a webhost in a unitTest, but I have no clue on how to setup the routing without controllers and actions. Let alone how to setup the webhook.

> UnitTest1.cs

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IWebHost myHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001/")
            .Build();


        myHost.Run();
        
    }
```

> Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /* configure any services you need here */
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Output a "hello world" to the user who accesses the server
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, w!");
        });
    }
}
```

> WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Load receivers
    }

}
```

I've tried to simply make an HTTPOST and HTTPGET methods to receive the postman messages, but honestly i don't know how it works.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SendHere")]
    public void Post(object message)
    {
        var receivedMSG = ($"Received webhook: {message}");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetHere")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string echo)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(echo, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };
        return resp;
    }
```

How i would i go about setting up a webhook end point from within a unittest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work!

**UnitTest1.cs**

```
public class UnitTest1
{

    private const string url = "http://localhost:5001";

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        CreateHostBuilder().Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseUrls(url);
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**Controllers/TestController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    }
}
```

> http://localhost:5001/Test    >     { "One", "Two", "Three" }